# Driving in the UK with foreign registration number

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-citizens, vehicle-registration

I have been driving a vehicle with bulgarian reg number since 28th January 2014 and my car got confiscated tonight as I did not managed to give them a proof I could drive it here. However, I am checking the documents I have and everything is legitimate , I have a valid certificate of insurance and proof of ownership of the vehicle and my valid bulgarian driving licence. As I am planning to travel to Bulgaria by car but just calculated that it has been more than 6 month in here could anyone please advice me what my next step would be?

Comment: What country was this in? And how long have you been in that country driving the car for?

Comment: Sorry, I still stressed from what happened. I drove it in the UK. I have been told that I could drive a car up to 6 months in the UK if I am planning to leave the country soon or if I am travelling a lot. So today on my way to the local supermarket I got stopped by the police and they started an argument that I am a resident and therefore I should have registered my car with bulgarian number 14 days after my arrival! So now I am very worried I found my insurance certificate which is valid, my ownership certificate and when the car was brought in the UK 29/01/2014, I will go and collect the car

Comment: tomorrow but am not sure if I can drive the car anymore in the UK?? I am also scared that when I try and leave the country they will confiscate it again as it is not legitimate? Any idea what is the best thing I should do! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: See the duplicate question for all the details. You basically need to provide enough proof to show that you are not a UK resident

Comment: I have read that but I am still unclear what about the time that I could stay here and can I leave the country now!

Comment: @llieave: you entered the country on 29/01/2014? That was more than 6 months ago

Comment: yeah it is now 6 or 7 days more so am I still allowed to leave the country with my car?

Comment: @Ilieva: I think the best you could achieve (if your car is confiscated by the police) is to get a trailer and use it to move the car to the border. You will definitely not be able to drive it in the UK (even to the border) anymore without registering it.

Comment: these are the conditions that you need to have so you  could drive the car You can usually use a vehicle displaying non-UK number plates without needing to tax or register it in the UK if all of the following apply:

you’re visiting the UK and don’t plan to live here
you only use the vehicle up to 6 months in a 12-month period (1 single visit, or several shorter visits adding up to a 6-month period)
the vehicle is registered and taxed in its home country